# Android Development: how to set up AVD and SDK manager?

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device

I am having a problem in that I cannot find the AVD and SDK manager within Eclipse: The tutorial I am working on states it should be under preferences in the Window Tab yet I cannot locate it?

I cant seem to print screen to illustrate further.

The Youtube Tutorial I am working on:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPFUTJgvVpQ&list=PL2F07DBCDCC01493A

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try following the steps on this page instead:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Comment: Thanks, I believe that this link will give me all tools necessary for android development?

Comment: actually that page looks like a better bet. One tip is that when you install the SDK try to avoid Program Files and install in your user directory instead, that way you have write permission when you need to update it.